# NameValueCollection to string? Help

Tags: c#, service, query-string, namevaluecollection

The service I've written waits for requests and when one arrives it extracts the querystring, parses it and saves the values in database. However, for some odd reason I cannot use the System.Web.HttpUtility class with windows service. I've tried some of the examples i've managed to find on the net but all of them included HttpUtility class.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you try referencing the System.Web assembly in the service?

Comment: that I did not do. Works fine now. if there was a way to upvote your comment i would, but I cannot because I don't have the priviledge. Thanks tho!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you included the System.Web.dll assembly in your project?